# RoR: Removing form fields by jQuery, remote call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am having some problems removing some fields from a form with the jQuery remove() function.  In the view I have a form.  This form has a looped set of fields for some sub-elements.  The user can remove each set.  I use a remote call to a destroy method in my controller which calls a js file with a jquery which will fadeout and remove the div in which the relevant set of fields is.

My problem is that although the object is destroyed and the div fades out nicely, the fields remain active and thus obviously gives an error when the form is posted.

I have tried to add a fieldset tag and remove that in addition to the div, and also tried to disable the whole fieldset, but the result is the same.  The fields are still being posted (and since the object has been destroyed an error is returned).

This is the relevant part of the view

```
- i = 0             # a bit crude, see if can make index count more Railsy
= f.simple_fields_for :fund_levels do |fl|
   %div{id: "flheader-#{fl.object.id}"}
     %div
       = link_to "Sponsor levels", "#", :class => "show_hide", :id => "initiator1_fl#{i}", :style=>"margin-bottom:2px;", :onclick=>"return false"
     %div{:class => "slidingDiv #{fund_levels_last?(i, @fund_level_count) ? "shown": "hidd" } whitebg leftadj", :id=>"body_fl#{i}", :style=>"width:100%;" }
       = fl.input :title
       = fl.input :description
       = fl.input :maxnumber
       = fl.input :price
       %div{:style => "float: right; padding: 20px 20px 20px 0"}
         = fund_levels_last?(i, @fund_level_count) ? ( link_to "add new level", ad, {class: 'button orange sm'} ) : ( link_to "remove", accounts_ad_fund_level_path(ad, fl.object.id), {:class => 'button orange sm', :method => :delete, :remote => true, :confirm => t('q.are_you_sure')} )
       - i += 1
```

And this is the jQuery call

```
$('#flheader-<%= @fundlevel.id %>').fadeOut(300, function() { $(this).remove(); });
```

As I said, the object is successfully destroyed and the div fades out.  I just need to figure out how to remove the deleted object (set of fields) entirely from the page when it is posted.

**EDIT: The problem seems to be that simple_fields_for generates a hidden ID field immediately in the beginning of each loop.  That means that the ID field actually is outside the div that is being destroyed and thus is being posted.  Any thoughts on how to force the hidden id field to be inside the DIV?**

Comment: I know the question about jQuery fadeout and remove have been asked and answered here many times, but they all give the answer of including a remove function on fadeout return (fadeOut(300, function() { $(this).remove(); ) which doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a few more hours of research I solved the problem.

First of all - to avoid the object ID being printed outside the looped div, it was necessary to include the object id as a hidden fields manually.  When this is done, simple_forms won't automatically include it, and you can therefore place it where you want it.

In addition it was necessary to make a change to the main form controller to allow_destroy and reject_if values.all was blank.